# Kendo UI (Scheduler) - Edit Event onClick of Button

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I am using Kendo UI - **Scheduler** to create Events on Calendar.

I want to Edit an already added event by clicking on "**Edit**" button.

Currently, Kendo is providing only on double clicking on the Event.

> **[Online Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/azaFO)**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scheduler/index">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />

    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/js/kendo.timezones.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
<div class="container">
  
  
  <div class="rp-calendar">
    <div id="socialMediaCalendar"></div>
  </div>
  
</div>
<!-- Calendar Scheduler (Content Templates) -->
<script id="event-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
  <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="scheduler-template-table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="et-time" width="1%" nowrap>#: kendo.toString(start, "HH:mm") #</td>
        <td class="et-content"><h3>#: title #</h3><p>#: description #</p></td>
        <td class="et-options" align="right">
          <input type="button" value="Edit" id="eventEdit" class="k-button">
        </td>
      </tr>
    <tbody>
  </table>
</script>
<!-- /Calendar Scheduler (Content Templates) -->

<!-- Calendar Scheduler (Tooltip Templates) -->
<script id="calendarPopupTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template"> 
  #var uid = target.attr("data-uid");#
  #var scheduler = target.closest("[data-role=scheduler]").data("kendoScheduler");#
  #var model = scheduler.occurrenceByUid(uid);#

  #if(model) {#

  <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="scheduler-template-table stt-tooltip">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="et-time" width="1%" nowrap>#=kendo.format('{0:HH:mm}',model.start)#</td>
        <td class="et-content" valign="middle"><h3>#: model.title #</h3><p>#=model.description#</p></td>
      </tr>
    <tbody>
  </table>
  #} else {#
  <p>No event data is available</p>
  #}#
</script>
<!-- /Calendar Scheduler (Tooltip Template) -->
  
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 var date = new Date();
 var _data = new kendo.data.SchedulerDataSource({
     data: [
       {
       eventID: 1,
       title: "Main Heading",
       start: new Date("2015/12/17 01:00 AM"),
       end: new Date("2015/12/17 01:20 AM"),
       isAllDay: false,
       description: "Lorem ipsum content",
       },
       {
       eventID: 2,
       title: "Heading 2",
       start: new Date("2015/12/17 06:15 AM"),
       end: new Date("2015/12/17 06:30 AM"),
       isAllDay: false,
       description: "New content goes here...",
       },
       {
        eventID: 3,
        title: "Heading 2",
        start: new Date("2015/12/17 09:15 PM"),
        end: new Date("2015/12/17 09:30 PM"),
        isAllDay: false,
        description: "More content goes here...",
        },
     ],

     schema: {
       model : { id : "eventID" }
     }

   });

   function save(){
     console.log(_data);    
   }

   $('#socialMediaCalendar').kendoScheduler({
    
  eventTemplate: $("#event-template").html(),
     height: 600,
     messages: {
      today: "Today",
       },
       //editable: false,
     ShowFooter: "false",
     views: [
       { type: "day", title: "Day", selectedDateFormat: "{0:dddd}", showWorkHours: false, selected: true },
       { type: "month" },
     ],
     
     dataBound: function() {
            var scheduler = this;
            
            var allDayEventBlock = scheduler.wrapper.find(".k-scheduler-layout>tbody>tr:nth-child(1)");
            var dayViewTimesBlock = scheduler.wrapper.find(".k-scheduler-layout .k-scheduler-times");
            var tdNoWorkHours = scheduler.wrapper.find(".k-scheduler-layout .k-nonwork-hour");
            var prevCalContentRef = scheduler.wrapper.find(".k-scheduler-layout td.et-options #previewCalDayContent");
            
            allDayEventBlock.remove();
            dayViewTimesBlock.remove();
            tdNoWorkHours.closest("tr").remove();
            prevCalContentRef.attr("href", "#pn-modal-day-preview");          
            
            
          },

     save: save,
     dataSource:_data,
    
     
   });

   $(function () {
     $("#socialMediaCalendar").kendoTooltip({
       filter: ".k-event",
       position: "top",
       width: 250,
       content: kendo.template($('#calendarPopupTemplate').html())
     });
   });
   
});  
</script>

<style>
  .rp-calendar{margin:auto;width:80%;margin-top:50px;}
form{max-width:500px;margin:20px auto;}
 
.rp-calendar{background: #f6f7f8;border:1px solid #e9e9eb;color:#585858;position: relative;}
.rp-calendar table{border-collapse:collapse;}
.rp-calendar .k-scheduler-toolbar{border:0;padding:20px;}
.rp-calendar .k-scheduler-toolbar .k-scheduler-navigation .k-nav-current,.rp-calendar .k-scheduler-toolbar .k-scheduler-navigation .k-nav-current a{color:#6e6e6e;font-size:26px;}
.rp-calendar .k-scheduler-toolbar .k-scheduler-navigation .k-nav-current{position:relative;top:3px;}
.rp-calendar .k-scheduler-toolbar ul li .k-i-calendar{display:none;}

.rp-calendar .k-scheduler-toolbar .k-scheduler-views .k-state-default,.rp-calendar .k-scheduler-toolbar .k-scheduler-views .k-state-default a{background:transparent !important;}
.rp-calendar .k-scheduler-toolbar .k-scheduler-views .k-state-default{border: 1px solid #d7d7d7 !important;}
.rp-calendar .k-scheduler-toolbar .k-scheduler-views li:first-child,.rp-calendar .k-scheduler-toolbar .k-scheduler-views li:first-child > a{border-right:none;}

.rp-calendar .k-scheduler-toolbar .k-scheduler-views .k-state-selected,.rp-calendar .k-scheduler-toolbar .k-scheduler-views .k-state-selected a{background: #0c8aff !important;color:#fff !important;}
.rp-calendar .k-scheduler-toolbar .k-scheduler-views .k-state-selected{border: 1px solid #d7d7d7;position: relative;}

.rp-calendar .k-scheduler-toolbar .k-scheduler-views .k-state-selected:before {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid #0c8aff;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  content: '';
  right: 0;
  width: 10px;
  margin: auto;
}

.rp-calendar .k-scheduler-toolbar .k-scheduler-views .k-state-selected:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -18px;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 9px solid transparent;
  border-top: 9px solid #0c8aff;
  border-left: 9px solid transparent;
  content: '';
  right: 0;
  width: 8px;
  margin: auto;
}


.rp-calendar .k-scheduler-header th,.rp-calendar .k-scheduler-header td,.rp-calendar .k-scheduler-content td{border: 1px solid #fff;}
.rp-calendar .k-scheduler-header th{text-align: center; background-color: #f6f7f8;border: 1px solid #fff;color: #585858;}
.rp-calendar .k-scheduler-content td{color:#585858;}
.rp-calendar .k-scheduler-monthview .k-scheduler-content td{vertical-align:bottom;color:#585858;}
.rp-calendar .k-scheduler-content td.k-other-month{background:#e9e9e9 !important;}

.rp-calendar .k-event{background-image:none !important;}
.rp-calendar .k-scheduler-monthview .k-scheduler-content .k-event{text-indent:-9999px;height: 15px !important;width: 15px !important;border:0 !important;border-radius: 100%;padding: 0;margin: 0;overflow: hidden;line-height: initial;}
.rp-calendar .k-scheduler-monthview .k-scheduler-content table.scheduler-template-table td.et-time{background:#6078aa !important;padding: 0;width: 15px;height: 15px;margin: 0;}
.rp-calendar .k-scheduler-monthview .k-scheduler-content .k-event h4,.rp-calendar .k-scheduler-monthview .k-scheduler-content .k-event p{display:none !important;}
.rp-calendar .k-scheduler-monthview .k-scheduler-content .k-event-actions,.rp-calendar .k-scheduler-monthview .k-scheduler-content .k-resize-handle{display:none !important;}

.rp-calendar .k-scheduler-content td.k-other-month span{opacity:0.3;}
.rp-calendar .k-scheduler-monthview .k-scheduler-table td:nth-child(even){background-color: #e9e9e9;}
.rp-calendar .k-scheduler-monthview .k-scheduler-table tbody tr>td,.rp-calendar .k-scheduler-monthview .k-scheduler-table tbody tr:nth-child(6n+1) td:nth-child(even),.rp-calendar .k-scheduler-monthview .k-scheduler-table tbody tr:nth-child(6n+3) td:nth-child(even),.rp-calendar .k-scheduler-monthview .k-scheduler-table tbody tr:nth-child(6n+3) td:nth-child(even){ background:#e9e9e9}
.rp-calendar .k-scheduler-monthview .k-scheduler-table tbody tr:nth-child(6n+1) td:nth-child(odd),.rp-calendar .k-scheduler-monthview .k-scheduler-table tbody tr:nth-child(6n+3) td:nth-child(odd),.rp-calendar .k-scheduler-monthview .k-scheduler-table tbody tr:nth-child(6n+5) td:nth-child(odd){ background:#f6f7f8}
.rp-calendar .k-scheduler-monthview .k-scheduler-table tbody tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(even){background:#f6f7f8;}
.rp-calendar .k-scheduler-monthview td[role='gridcell']{height:120px !important;}

.rp-calendar .k-scheduler-dayview .k-scheduler-content{background:#f6f7f8;}
.rp-calendar .k-scheduler-footer,.rp-calendar .k-scheduler-dayview .k-event-actions{display:none !important;}
.rp-calendar .k-scheduler-dayview .schedule-times-hide .k-scheduler-times{display:none !important;}
.rp-calendar .k-scheduler-dayview .k-event{background-color:#fff;border:1px solid #efefef;}
.rp-calendar .k-scheduler-dayview .k-middle-row{display:none;}
/* .rp-calendar .k-scheduler-dayview .k-nonwork-hour{display:none !important;} */

.rp-calendar .k-scheduler-dayview  .k-event{position:static !important;height:auto !important;width: 100% !important;left: 0 !important;overflow: hidden;margin-bottom: 10px;}
.rp-calendar .k-scheduler-dayview .k-scheduler-content table.k-scheduler-table{display:none !important;}

.rp-calendar .k-scheduler-content table.scheduler-template-table td{border:0;padding: 10px;vertical-align:middle;}
.rp-calendar .k-scheduler-content table.scheduler-template-table td.et-time{background-color:#efefef;font-size: 18px;font-weight:bold;color: #555;}
.rp-calendar .k-scheduler-content table.scheduler-template-table td.et-content{font-size:13px;}
.rp-calendar .k-scheduler-content table.scheduler-template-table td.et-content h3{color:#444;margin:0 0 5px 0;}
.rp-calendar .k-scheduler-content table.scheduler-template-table td.et-content p{margin:0;}
.rp-calendar .k-scheduler-content table.scheduler-template-table td.et-options a{margin-left:15px;}


.campaign .k-animation-container,.campaign .k-widget.k-tooltip{width:400px !important;}
.campaign .k-widget.k-tooltip{/* border-color: #DEDCDC;background-color: #fff;color: #585858; */padding:0;}
.campaign .k-callout-s{border-top-color: #fff; z-index: 2;bottom: -18px;border-width: 9px;}
.campaign .k-callout-s:before{border:1px solid red;}

.scheduler-template-table.stt-tooltip td{padding:10px;background:#fff;}
.scheduler-template-table.stt-tooltip td.et-time{font-size:18px;background: #efefef;border-right: 1px solid #DCDCDC;}
.scheduler-template-table.stt-tooltip td.et-content{text-align:left;}
.scheduler-template-table.stt-tooltip td.et-content h3{font-size:18px;color:#0c8aff !important;margin-bottom:5px;}
.scheduler-template-table.stt-tooltip td.et-content p{text-align:left;}
.scheduler-template-table.stt-tooltip .k-callout-s{border-color:#fff;}
  </style>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

I have not read your question fully. What I understood is to open editor popup on button click event. If it is correct then "addEvent" function will solve your query.